# AWK removes my spaces

Tags: awk, tabular

I have a data like

```
31 text text t   text  ?::"!!/
2 te    text 32 +ěščřžý
43 te www  ##
```

It is output from `uniq -c`

I need to get something like

```
text text t   text  ?::"!!/
te    text 32 +ěščřžý
te www  ##
```

I tried to use something like

```
a=$1;
$1=""
$0=substr($0, 2);
printf $0;
print "";
```

But it removes me spaces and I got something like

```
text text t text ?::"!!/
te text 32 +ěščřžý
te www ##
```

And I need to save the number too.

Is there anyone, who knows how to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by `And I need to save the number too.`?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to remove the leading digits from each line, `sed` will be simpler for this task

```
sed -E 's/^[0-9]+ //' file
```

`awk` normalizes white space with the default FS.  You can do the same with sub in `awk` if there is more processing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$ echo "31 text text t   text" |awk '{gsub($1FS$2,$2);print}'
text text t   text
```

You can also try

```
$ echo "31 text text t   text" |awk '{gsub(/^[0-9]+/,"");print}'
 text text t   text
```

But in this case you will have a leading space in front of each line.

Comment: Don't do `gsub($1FS$2,$2)` as it's too fragile if/when the input contains regexp or back reference metacharacters.

Comment: It is great, but there can be numbers in the text part. And uniq -c generate spaces before table.

Comment: @NitramNekonečný if your input has spaces at the start of lines then show that in your sample input so we're not trying to help you solve a problem other than the one you actually have.

Comment: @NitramNekonečný By the way if you combine uniq -c |column -t leading spaces will be removed. Also if you remove the -c from uniq you will get the same results without the counting part in front....

Answer (score 0):

```
$ seq 5 | uniq -c
      1 1
      1 2
      1 3
      1 4
      1 5

$ seq 5 | uniq -c | awk '{sub(/^ *[^ ]+ +/,"")}1'
1
2
3
4
5

$ seq 5 | uniq -c | sed 's/^ *[^ ]* *//'
1
2
3
4
5
```